# Powershell script to "monitor" directory(s) for new files and move to new location(s)

Tags: powershell

I'm setting up a directory process for file signing by operators. These files need processing once signed so the next operator is aware of the previous process being complete.

Step 1. Initial file is created in X:\'operator name'\'Customer Name'

Step 2. Operator signed the file and places signed version in  x:\'Operator name'\'Customer Name'\Signed

Step 3. An administrator will launch a batch file or script from their desktop that will move all files created in any X:\'Operator Name'\'Customer Name'\Signed folder into it's corresponding X:\'Customer Name' folder.

A list of operators will be maintained - probably in the batch file. This already exists in a central excel file.

All files will be .pdf
Each operator will have there own folder on X:\
Each operator has an infinite potential number of customer folders.

All operator and customer folders are created automatically in vb so naming will be identical.

Any help appreciated!

Thanks,

```bsh
# Defines a list of operators. Must be identical to those in the main PDF operators table
$operatorlist = (
                "Operator One",
                "Operator Two",
                "Operator three",
                "Operator Four",
                "Operator Five",
                "Operator Six"
                )

# Defining the variables
$nametoFind = "\Signed"

foreach ( $FTM in $operatorlist )
{
$sourceFolder = ( JOIN-PATH "X:\"  $operatorlist )
#define the file to move
$FTM = Get-ChildItem $sourceFolder -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name.Endswith($nametoFind)}
$customerpath = Split-Path - Path $FTM -Parent -Resolve | Split-Path -Leaf

}
```

Comment: Well try some and if they fail to work, you may have enough information to create an on topic question. We're not here to do it for you before you've even attempted it yourself.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like this would be better as a pwoershell script. I'll have a look and come back.

Answer (score 1):

This response to too long to put in a comment. So, putting here:

Why not just use Windows FSRM (File System Resource Manager) service to do this vs scripting. It's a purpose built service to look at data files and take actions defined. You can look at content of a file and make decisions on what to do with them. Much of the info you'll find talks to Windows FCI (File Classification Infrastructure). Yet, nothing prevents you from using FSRM for this generic purpose. See this info:

[Windows Server 2012 > Using File Server Resource Manager (FSRM) to Move Files Containing Sensitive Data](https://www.interfacett.com/blogs/using-file-server-resource-manager-fsrm-to-move-files-containing-sensitive-data)

If you want to use PowerShell for this, then you'll look to Async FileSystemWatcher implementation. There are prebuilt scripts on the MS PowerShellGallery.com that can get you started. Download and use as is or refactor as needed for your use case.

Example(s):

[Powershell FileSystemWatcher](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b)

This script uses the .net FileSystemWatcher class to subscribe to 'create', 'change' and 'delete' events on files or folders in the NTFS filesystem. It can be used to monitor a folder or folders, and can be modified to perform any action upon the triggering of these events.

[Download : FileSystemWatcher.ps1](http://Download)

[Monitor folder for file system events](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Monitor-folder-for-file-e6a30002)

> .Synopsis
>   Monitors a folder for changes using non-persistent asynchronous events
>
> .Description
>   A wrapper around IO.FileSystemWatcher and Register-ObjectEvent to monitor a folder for file system events (Created, Deleted, Changed, and/or Renamed)

[Download : Monitor-Folder.ps1](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Monitor-folder-for-file-e6a30002/file/133868/1/Monitor-Folder.ps1)